# Find last and next item in mutlidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, pagination

i have been searching the internet the past few days for a solution to my problem but so far nothing. I have an array of pages that i need to handle as a pagination, that is show my the past item and next item. The array content can change depending what section your viewing but the setup is always the same.

**My array:**

```
Array
(
    [19] => Array
        (
            [titill] => Kafli 1
            [slug] => kafli1
            [undir] => Array
                (
                    [21] => Array
                        (
                            [titill] => 1.1 Serhljodar
                            [slug] => serhljodar
                            [kaflar] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 24
                                            [titill] => Æfing 1
                                            [slug] => aefing1
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 25
                                            [titill] => Æfing 2
                                            [slug] => æfing2
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 26
                                            [titill] => Próf 1
                                            [slug] => prof1
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [22] => Array
                        (
                            [titill] => 1.2. Samhljóðar
                            [slug] => samhljodar
                        )

                    [23] => Array
                        (
                            [titill] => 1.3 Málnotkun
                            [slug] => malnotkun
                        )

                )

        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [titill] => Kafli 2
            [slug] => kafli2
        )

)
```

The array keys are the post_id's and the slug's are the urls. To explain what i'm trying to acchieve with this array i've writtend down a few examples what i want to do:

- if i'm viewing `localhost/kafli1` i would see that the next item is
  `localhost/kafli1/serhljodar` (key #21) and the no previous item.
- if i'm viewing `localhost/kafli1/serhljodar` i should see that the next
  item is `localhost/kafli1/serhljodar/aefing1` and the previous item
  is `localhost/kafli`.
- if 8'm viewing `localhost/kafli/serhljodar/prof1`
  (ID #26) i should see that the next item is `localhost/kafli1/samhljodar` and previous item is `localhost/kafli1/serhljodar/aefing2`

I've been told to use array_slice but so far it hasn't been much of a help. Can you good people help me with this problem?

---

**EDIT:**
It has been said that the array itself is the problem. Below is the sql this array is populated from:

```
INSERT INTO `posts` (`id`, `parent_id`, `category`, `position`, `post_slug`, `titill`) VALUES
(9, 0, 3, 0, 'islenska-stig1', 'Íslenska stig 1'),
(19, 9, 3, 0, 'kafli1', 'Kafli 1'),
(20, 9, 3, 0, 'kafli2', 'Kafli 2',),
(21, 19, 3, 0, 'serhljodar', '1.1 Serhljodar'),
(22, 19, 3, 0, 'samhljodar', '1.2. Samhljóðar'),
(23, 19, 3, 0, 'malnotkun', '1.3 Málnotkun'),
(24, 21, 3, 1, 'aefing1', 'Æfing 1'),
(26, 21, 3, 3, 'prof1', 'Próf 1');
```

If the array is the problem how can i succesfully create a pagination array out of these posts so the parent_id align's itself under the correct id so i can get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => islenska-stig1
    [1] => kafli1
    [2] => serhljodar
    [3] => aefing1
    [4] => prof1
    [5] => samhljodar
    [6] => malnotkun
    [6] => kafli2
)
```

Comment: Are functions like `current()`, `next()`, `end()` not suited for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a suspicion that the structure of your array is the problem.

It sounds as if you're trying to use your multi-d array as a linear array. So my recommendation is that you iterate through everything, pushing each item into a single dimensional array. and just reference your previous and next items with currentIndex + - 1

Comment: I thought of that too. however i'm not sure how to set it up otherwise without opening up three or four connections to the database. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the type of data structure you are looking for is the doubly linked list. It represents a list of elements that have pointers for the next element and the previous element.

Check out this link to see if it meets your requirements:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.spldoublylinkedlist.php

Comment: sounds interesting ... however not quite sure how to test it or implement it :/